# What do I really need to install into VS 2015, to create a simple universal app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, installation, win-universal-app

I'll try to be concrete so this doesn't get tagged as a discussion question.

I'm a complete programming beginner learning C#, and one exercise includes creating a universal win10 app. Except my version of Visual Studio 2015 doesn't have this type of template pre-installed, so I clicked to download it. Turns out it's 12 Gb.

My question is whether I can opt out of some of the things that Microsoft want to install, specifically "Common tools for Visual C++ 2015". I tried unchecking it, but then it automatically also removed "Tools (1.4) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)", which seems a lot more important. So maybe I need tools for C++, even though I'm not using C++?

I notice there is another one you can check, called "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240)", and I thought perhaps I can choose that one instead. This one allows me to uncheck C++, which gives me back 6Gb of harddrive.

Since I'm just trying to learn, I don't need the app to be compatible with win8, I don't need to emulate a phone or Xbox or what have you. I just need to make an app with a GUI, to see how it's done.

Comment: Are you trying VS 2015 or with Update 3

Comment: It wants to install Update 3 as well, so I'll have it once I've installed the universal app tools.

Comment: why not try it and find out? You can always install the other parts later.

Comment: that's a good idea, but I have two questions: 1) how do I uninstall 10240 if it turns out to be wrong? (because I would like that extra 6Gb back) 2) Where do I find the tools and the 10586 SDK to download?

Comment: I think you have selected the VC++ mobile development also , please check & remove VC++ mobile development and check again

Comment: By default, it has checked:

- update 3

- Common tools for Visual C++ 2015

- Microsoft Web Developer Tools

- Tools (1.4) and Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)